# Flutter - Custom slider value indicator. How to get the slider's center position

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-layout, flutter-slider

I am trying to implement a custom progress indicator for flutter slider. As for now, I have the given code that draws the indicator.

```dart
class InsideSliderValueIndicator extends SliderComponentShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.zero;
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    bool isDiscrete,
    TextPainter labelPainter,
    RenderBox parentBox,
    SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    double value,
  }) {
    final sliderWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    final sliderBoxOffset = parentBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    labelPainter.paint(
        context.canvas,
        Offset(sliderBoxOffset.dx  + sliderWidth / 2 - labelPainter.width / 2,
            center.dy - labelPainter.height / 2));
  }
}
```

I have also customized the slider to remove the thumb. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Slider result]
As you can see, the text is not centered in the slider.

The problem with this code is that `sliderBoxOffset` doesn't return the box of the "slider", but of the parent card, and `center` is actually the position of your thumb on the slider relative to the parent.

**So my question is**: How can I get the center of the slider from the given parameters ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a weird solution that works for my use-case

```
    final sliderWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    final halfSliderWidth = sliderWidth / 2;
    final translateX = value < 0.5 ? halfSliderWidth - (value * sliderWidth) : halfSliderWidth - (value * sliderWidth);
    labelPainter.paint(context.canvas, center.translate(translateX - labelPainter.width / 2, -labelPainter.height / 2));
```

I'm however pretty sure this won't work if the slider is not centered in its parent. I'm still wondering if there is a less dirty way to do this.